# открытое использование android studio

Tags: android-studio, лицензирование

Не могу найти правила пользования андроид студией. Необходимо будучи работая в фирме скачать, установить и написать приложение в андроид студии. Предшественник по рабочему месту "кричал", что ничего стороннего устанавливать нельзя. В лицензионном соглашении не нашел информации о правилах пользования. Может кто знает?)

Comment: Не нашел - значит нет ограничений. Иначе было бы на первых строках. Пользуюсь студией, скачанной с официального сайта уже несколько лет, размещаю приложения в плеймаркете, никогда и ни от кого не было вопросов о лицензии. Поищи на странице скачивания кнопку "купить" )))

Comment: Неправда, если нет лицензии это наоборот означает, что все права остаются за автором, то есть использовать софт вообще нельзя - можно только смотреть :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio лицензирован под лицензией [Apache License Version 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), что в переводе на русский язык, если отвлечься от юридической шелухи означает:

> даёт пользователю право использовать программное обеспечение для любых целей, свободно изменять и распространять изменённые копии, за исключением названия.
> Данная лицензия не ставит условием неизменность лицензии распространения программного обеспечения, и не настаивает даже на сохранении его бесплатного и открытого статуса. Единственным условием, накладываемым лицензией Apache, является информирование получателя о факте использования исходного кода. Таким образом, в противоположность copyleft-лицензиям, получатель модифицированной версии не обязательно получает все права, изначально предоставляемые лицензией Apache.

Файл с лицензией обычно находится в корневом каталоге Android Studio (называется `LICENSE.txt`)

С другой стороны если вы работаете в компании, то у каждой компании существует своя внутренняя политика в отношении использования того или иного софта, неважно - лицензирован софт или нет. Соответственно, разумно будет затребовать у своего IT департамента эту политику.

Comment: Компания маленькая, тут нет IT департамента) Предупредили что надо лицензии читать . Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ну тогда идите в админу и решите вопрос. Самый главный вопрос обычно это обход файрволла, Студия без доступа к сети в общем то бесполезна.